# How to calculate the time complexity for Leetcode's Longest Common Prefix with a solution using Tries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, trie

I am trying to improve my problem solving skills, and have solved problem #14 in Leetcode "Longest Common Prefix" using the Trie data structure.

My solution runs in 106ms and beats 42.91%. However, I am not really sure how to find out the time complexity of my solution.

```
1. public class Solution
2. {
3.     public class TrieNode
4.     {
5.         public bool IsEndOfString = false;
6.         public TrieNode[]? Children;
7.         public int Visits = 0;
8.     }
9.     
10.     public class Trie
11.     {
12.         private const int AlphabetSize = 26;
13.         private TrieNode _root;
14.         private int _max = 0;
15.     
16.         public Trie()
17.         {
18.             _root = new TrieNode()
19.             {
20.                 Visits = -1,
21.                 Children = new TrieNode[AlphabetSize]
22.             };
23.         }
24.     
25.         public void Insert(string key)
26.         {
27.             TrieNode currentNode = _root;
28. 
29.             foreach (char c in key)
30.             {
31.                 int currentIndex = c - 'a';
32.     
33.                 if (currentNode.Children[currentIndex] is null)
34.                     currentNode.Children[currentIndex] = new TrieNode()
35.                     {
36.                         Children = new TrieNode[AlphabetSize]
37.                     };
38. 
39.                 currentNode = currentNode.Children[currentIndex];
40. 
41.                 currentNode.Visits++;
42.     
43.                 if (currentNode.Visits > _max)
44.                     _max = currentNode.Visits;
45.             }
46.     
47.             currentNode.IsEndOfString = true;
48.         }
49.     
50.         public List<string> FindAllPrefixes(string[] strs)
51.         {
52.             StringBuilder prefixBuilder = new StringBuilder();
53.             List<string> listOfPrefixes = new List<string>();
54.         
55.             foreach (string key in strs)
56.             {
57.                 TrieNode currentNode = _root;
58.         
59.                 foreach (char c in key)
60.                 {
61.                     var currentIndex = c - 'a';
62.                     if (currentNode.Children[currentIndex] is not null && currentNode.Children[currentIndex].Visits == _max)
63.                     {
64.                         prefixBuilder.Append((char) (currentIndex + 'a'));
65.                         currentNode = currentNode.Children[currentIndex];
66.                     }
67.                     else
68.                         break;
69.                 }
70.                 listOfPrefixes.Add(prefixBuilder.ToString());
71.                 prefixBuilder.Clear();
72.             }
73. 
74.             return listOfPrefixes;
75.         }
76.     }
77. 
78.     public string LongestCommonPrefix(string[] strs)
79.     {
80.         if (strs.Length == 1)
81.             return strs[0];
82. 
83.         Trie trie = new Trie();
84. 
85.         foreach (string str in strs)
86.             trie.Insert(str);
87.         
88.         List<string> listOfPrefixes = trie.FindAllPrefixes(strs);
89.         listOfPrefixes.Sort((a, b) => b.Length.CompareTo(a.Length));
90.         string longestPrefix = listOfPrefixes[0];
91.         
92.         foreach (string str in strs)
93.         {
94.             if (!str.StartsWith(longestPrefix))
95.                 return string.Empty;
96.         }
97. 
98.         return longestPrefix;
99.     }
100. }
```

My guess goes like this:

- On line 88, it should be O(n * m), where m is the number of strs and n is the total length of all keys.
- On line 89, O(k * j) where k is the number of prefixes and j is the total length of all prefixes.
- On line 92, O(m * p) where m is the number of strs and p is the length of the longest prefix from the list.
- This leaves the total complexity: `O(k * j * p * n * m ^ 2)`
  Please correct my explanation if it was inaccurate.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of `n`?

Comment: @trincot This is a valid point. Let me give an update the. On line 88, it should be O(n * m), where n is the number of strs and m is the numbet of keys. On line 89, O(k ^ 2) where k is the number of prefixes. On line 92, O(i) where i is the number of strs. This leaves the total complexity: O(n * m * K ^ 2 * i). Is this correct?

Comment: @iamhaitham I think trincot's point was, do you believe the time taken depends solely on the number of strings, or does it also depend on how long the strings are?

Comment: @Sneftel I think you are both leading me in the right direction. I have just updated it taking the lengths into account as you mentioned.